# Check to see if a CGRect intersects with an array of CGRects

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, cgrect, cgrectintersectsrect

I'm trying to see if a `CGRect`s intersects with any other `CGRect`s in an array before initializing the `CGRect`, but I am yet to find a fool proof method that works.

Note that intersection is the array of `CGRect`s. Any takes on how to do this? The method below doesn't work sometimes the generated `CGRect` intersects with one in the array I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
for element in intersection {
  while CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1, element) {
    xTemp = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.width - buttonWidth1)))
    yTemp = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.height - buttonWidth1)))
    rect1 = CGRect(x: xTemp, y: yTemp, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonWidth)
   }
 }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. The first pass through, rect1 will be uninitialized. Where does the starting value of rect1 come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make use of [CGRectIntersectsRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect):

```
let doesIntersect = arrayOfRects.reduce(false) {
    return $0 || CGRectIntersectsRect($1, testRect)
}
```

Or (thanks to Martin R for his suggestion), you could use the `contains` method instead of `reduce`:

```
let doesIntersect = arrayOfRects.contains { CGRectIntersectsRect($0, testRect) }
```

Comment: Using contains() instead of reduce() might be more effective, as it stops the iteration once an intersection is found.

Comment: Hmm... that would be clearly more effective, and more readable. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't know why, but almost always `reduce` come first into my mind; maybe I got too fund of reducers/transducers :P

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0:**

```
let rectToCompare: CGRect! // Assign your rect here
for index in 0..<self. arrayOfRects.count {
  let rect = self. arrayOfRects[index]
  if rect.intersects(rectToCompare) {
     // Write your logic here
  }
}
```

Happy Coding...!